# Why does this Coq Definition fail? Coq Namespace error for Inductive Type

Tags: coq

I have the following Inductive Type and a test function:

```
Inductive parameter : Type :=
| Nop
| OneP : forall A, A -> parameter  
| TwoP : forall (A : Type) (r : nat) (b : A), parameter
.
Check (TwoP nat 1 5).


Definition test (p : parameter) : option (nat * nat) :=
match p with 
| TwoP nat x y => Some (x, y)
| _ => None
end.
```

The test function fails with the error:

The term "Some (x, y)" has type "option (Datatypes.nat * nat)"
while it is expected to have type "option (Datatypes.nat * Datatypes.nat)".

I don't understand why my definition does not work. Is there a difference between nat and Datataypes.nat ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Coq, it is not possible to test what a type is.  Consider the following program:

```
Definition is_nat (A : Type) : bool :=
  match A with
  | nat => true
  | _   => false
  end.
```

If you try to run this, Coq tells you that the last branch is redundant, and rejects the definition. The issue is that `nat` is taken to be a variable name, not the `nat` data type from the standard library.  Therefore, the first branch matches every type `A`, and the last branch is redundant. In your example, the pattern `nat` ends up masking the data type `nat`, which is why you end up seeing the qualified name `Datatypes.nat`.

One way of solving this issue is to use a type of *codes* instead of `Type`. For instance:

```
Inductive type : Type :=
| Bool
| Nat.

Definition type_denote t : Type :=
  match t with
  | Bool => bool
  | Nat => nat
  end.

Coercion type_denote : type >-> Sortclass.

Inductive parameter : Type :=
| Nop
| OneP : forall (A : type), A -> parameter
| TwoP : forall (A : type) (r : nat) (b : A), parameter
.
Check (TwoP Nat 1 5).

Definition test (p : parameter) : option (nat * nat) :=
match p with
| TwoP Nat x y => Some (x, y)
| _ => None
end.
```

There are two issues with this solution. First, it requires you to anticipate all types that you will need in `parameter`, and add those in the definition of `type`. Second, it forces you to program with dependent types, which can be hard to manipulate. It might be possible to refactor your definitions to avoid the problem of type matching altogether, although there is no one-size-fits-all solution -- it depends on your application.

Comment: That was insightful, thanks. 
The use case here is to split instructions into a command and a parameter part.
E.g a cmd would be JmpZero with the parameter TwoP register expr.
Do you maybe know of resources that try to do something similar?